# Receiving error when creating new trigger on Apps Script

Tags: javascript

Receiving this error when trying to create a new trigger "Script authorization failed. Please check your pop-up blocker settings and try again."

Have attempted to allow this site to accept pop ups and even turning off the pop blocker but it hasnt made a difference. Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and managed to fix it by first manually executing my script from the script editor and granting the necessary permission at that stage, and then adding the trigger.

Comment: Same issue, but this did not solve it for me. The part that fails is a library, which works on its own, but fails when included from a different doc.

Comment: hm. it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all the libraries of your script and after that, configure the trigger.

During the configuration of the trigger, a pop-up will appear asking for permissions/authorizations.

After configuring the trigger add the libraries again.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the solution! Any idea why this works?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this when using the HEAD (development mode) deployment of libraries. To fix it, use a deployed version of the library instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, and **removing the Libraries** of the script fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the solution! Any idea why this works?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this worked for me.

What happened on my end is one of my library's version has been deleted and the version library on my script was not updated. Simply updating the version library fixed this error.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, this worked for me. Any idea why this works?